# Copy userprofiles

Tags: powershell, copy, user-profile

I am trying to copy selected folders from all user profiles, but obviously doing it wrong. Could you point me in the right direction?

```
$destination = "C:\Backup"

$folder = "Desktop",
          "Downloads",
          "Favorites",
          "Documents",
          "Music",
          "Pictures",
          "Videos" ,
          "AppData\Local\Mozilla",
          "AppData\Local\Google",
          "AppData\Roaming\Mozilla"

$computername = gc env:COMPUTERNAME
$userprofiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -Directory

foreach ($userprofile in $userprofiles) {
    Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -Directory

    foreach ($f in $folder) {
        $BackupSource = $userprofiles  + "\" + $f
        $BackupDestination = $destination + "\" + $computername + "\" + $userprofiles + "\" + $f
        Copy-Item -ErrorAction silentlyContinue -Recurse -Path  $BackupSource -Destination $BackupDestination
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you can start with telling us why this is obviously wrong? What's happening?

Comment: It is copying the whole c drive in folders in Desktop, downloads, and so on

Comment: Could you please add this to your code. `Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -Exclude Public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$destination = "C:\Backup"

$folder = "Desktop",
"Downloads",
"Favorites",
"Documents",
"Music",
"Pictures",
"Videos" ,
"AppData\Local\Mozilla",
"AppData\Local\Google",
"AppData\Roaming\Mozilla"


$computername = gc env:computername
$userprofiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -directory

foreach ($userprofile in $userprofiles){
    foreach ($f in $folder)
    {   
        $BackupSource = $userprofile.FullName  + "\" + $f
        $BackupDestination = $destination + "\" + $computername + "\" + $userprofile.Name + "\" + $f
        Copy-Item -ErrorAction silentlyContinue -recurse -Path  $BackupSource -Destination $BackupDestination
    }
}
```

You were referring to the directory itself, not the path. Let me know if it doesn't work!

**--Edit as per OP Request--**

```
$userprofiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -directory
```

This command gets all "Directory" under C:\Users. Note that it gets the **directory itself not just the path**. $userprofiles is an array, you will have to use it using the index (like $userprofiles[0]) or iterate it. That's what you are doing using `foreach ($userprofile in $userprofiles)`. (In your original code you have used $userprofiles which is the array itself, that's why it didn't work)

Ok, now to why you need **$userprofile.Name**. As I said, $userprofile is the directory itself which has attributes like Name, FullName, CreationTime etc. We've simply accessed those by $userprofile.FullName which gave the full path to the directory.

Comment: Also for the BackupSource and Destination he was using $userprofiles instead of $userprofile

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that.. But had it changed in the snippet.Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind clarify why $userprofile.FullName  and $userprofile.Name is necessary ?  so i could learn from this :)

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if you have questions. :)

Comment: Thanks that does make sense :)